# What are the advantages/disadvantages of having high mouse sensitivity in Moba games when playing skill-shot based characters?

Tags: league-of-legends, mouse

I play a lot of league of legends and I watch streams, Game-plays, LCS, etc, trying to improve and learn more. In one of the last games they talked about mouse sensitivity and how you could move across the map faster (not your champion just your view) with a high mouse sensitivity. Now I know if I were to increase my own settings it would take a while to get use to most probably so my question will be in three parts.

1. What advantage can I gain (aside from being able to see more of the map without losing sight of my lane) by increasing my own mouse sensitivity.
2. What disadvantage would I suffer if I did. Finally How can I go
3. about adjusting to the increased sensitivity.

My mouse is a gamer mouse just want to point that out a Headshot v8 activated gaming mouse to be exact. Like I said though after the conversation they had I'm starting to feel like I am not making the most out of it.

Comment: having a high mouse sense needs a lot of training. misclick rate will increase of course. But I know players who used to have a super fast mouse and they play well. So it's possible ;)

Comment: On the subject of mouse speed, get into the habit of right clicking practically always. Even when you are just waiting for a minion to get low on health so you can last hit it, constantly walk back and forth on the spot. This drastically increases your reaction time - say, if someone flashes out of a brush, you're already clicking and only need to move the mouse to decide where to escape to. A lot of players are surprised at the difference this makes. It also helps with last hit accuracy.

Comment: I will try that out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well it's pretty simple:

**You are faster** (Watch the mouse movements of [Wildturtle](http://www.twitch.tv/tsm_wildturtle/b/532539430) for example)
The cool thing is: The faster you move your mouse, the better your overview of the game is. You can basically "scout" The whole map with a fast mouse and then just hit space again to focus back on your character in under a second (you have to be able to realise what's going on in such a short amount of time though)

Of course it's not just like "Hey i'm gonna increase my mouse speed and then I'll reach diamond". That's where the second point you're asking is important:

The biggest disadvantage is you will play **awful** if you aren't used to it. You will missclick all the time and you will move your cursor too far if you have a sensitivity that is too high. It's also something that you can't learn in a short amount of time. If you want to go up for 1000 DPI it can really take a while (weeks maybe even months depending on how fast you get used to it). Also for practicing with increased mouse speed I wouldn't recommend MOBAs but Shooters or Games that require a high accuracy and speed (Osu is a great game for increasing mouse speed but usually shooters are more fun to play). Of course you can also practice it in League or other MOBAs.

I recommend going up only for about a maximum of 10% of your current speed at a time. Mistakes won't happen that often (they might still be game changing). And don't get frustrated if you make mistakes. It's completely normal and as already mentioned it's really hard to improve your mouse speed.

Comment: Are there any drills of sorts i can do on different games or even league of legends that will make the transition easier, yes I actually do watch wildturtle he is probably one of my favorite pro adcs next to piglet and uzi and I remember seeing him 1 v 1 kha and it was really insane to watch cause I mean the movement was "mind-blowing" I'm well aware it will take time to learn but i believe it is an invaluable skill to master. What would you suggest.. can you add it in your answer please

Comment: @Broken_Code As already mentioned [Osu](http://osu.ppy.sh/) is a great game to test accuracy and speed with a mouse (especially on high difficulty). Apart from that there isn't a lot that would come to my mind that's more effective than osu. Maybe just playing league itself with a very high DPI but doing this can be really frustrating. Personally I learned playing with a high DPI by just going up 10% every time I felt comfortable with the current speed. And you don't need 12k DPI to reach challenger it's just an advantage ;)

Comment: I actually did install osu a few weeks ago however I have been stuck because it just seemed so impossible until now with I suppose the mouse change i will get better it had never really crossed my mind though

Comment: @Broken_Code Well osu can sometimes be very frustrating and Boring but it really is great for learning speed and accuracy. If you're good at osu you will automatically become better in games where speed/accuracy is important. The only reason why it's not as frustrating as playing league, is because it's usually not competitive.

Comment: @Broken_Code actually i don't think there is any advantages of having high mouse sensitivity. You still have your minimap for game overview and you can even click on it to see what is going on. So no advantages imho